# Simple notifications work fine, but schedule notifications don't appear and no errors are shown

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I tried to make the scheduled notification, but it did not work, and there were no errors in the console. but simple notification works fine.
I checked all the Stackoverflow posts related to this similar topic and tried. nothing works.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:MoneyTracker/utils/const.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
  final notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('warning');

    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
          importance: Importance.max),
    );
  }


  Future<void> showDailyNotification() async {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate =
        tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, 19, 30);

     }
    try {
      if (scheduledDate.isAfter(currentDateTime)) {
        await notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          0,
          'Daily Notification',
          'This is your daily notification message.',
          tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledDate, tz.local),
          await notificationDetails(),
          androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.alarmClock,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        );
      } else {
        print('Invalid scheduledDate: Must be in the future.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 
  NotificationService().initNotification();

  NotificationService notif = NotificationService();
   tz.initializeTimeZones();
  notif.showDailyNotification();
 
  runApp(const Material());
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.MoneyTracker">
   <application
        android:label="MoneyTracker"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

</manifest>
```

These are my codes. Please check and help to solve it.